# Credit card charged but domain not booked by a domain registrar where should I go against an International Merchant

Tags: intellectual-property, international

Sav.com had latency in the month of October. Therefore, Domains were not posted in my account, but the amount debited from the credit card. The same is accepted in written correspondence by sav.com that I had no active domains in my account + they have also confessed that domains for which they have charged my credit card are also available open in the market to be booked by anyone. W

When I asked them why and how this happened they gave the hack theory that my account would have been compromised and domains would have been transferred or deleted. This is the case of complete fraud because the domains under question are still with a registry and open to be booked by any one in the market.

I am based in India, and the merchant is based in USA.

Is there any supervisory monitoring body that can ask domain registrar to process refund based on the relevant evidences.

Comment: The body doesn't really ask any question. Also, we cannot provide specific legal advice here. You could edit the question to make it about what the law permits or requires, and what kinds of courts deal with such a situation. You may get a better answer if you specify a jurisdiction, particularly a country.

Answer (score 2):

Ask the credit card to reverse the charge and do so promptly. This usually works and is probably you only cost effective remedy.